How edit rig bones after skinning?
During the posing phase, I noticed that the rig bones at the thumb are out of place.
Checked the metarig, everything is in the right place and so are the axes.
I re-generated the rig and the result is the same.
Then I change the rig bones in edit mode, and after i swich to pose mode mesh gonna crazy.
Do I need to delete the WeightPaint first, then rearrange bones in the edit mod, and re-add the WeightPaint?
Or is there an easier way?



